# Возникает ошибка при попытке сделать пост в INSTAGRAM используя instapy_cli

Tags: python, cookie, instagram, upload

```
from instapy_cli import client
username = 'username'
password = 'password'
image = 'test.jpg'
text = 'Hello World \n#Python\n#instapy_cli '
with client(username, password) as cli:
    cli.upload(image, text)
```

Прилетает ошибка 
[IG] not found cookie/cookie_file >> login as default
ClientError checkpoint_challenge_required (Code: 400, Response: {"message": "challenge_required", "challenge": {"url": "https://i.instagram.com/challenge/1407799808/CRMmDt7pdN/", "api_path": "/challenge/1407799808/CRMmDt7pdN/", "hide_webview_header": true, "lock": true, "logout": false, "native_flow": true}, "status": "fail", "error_type": "checkpoint_challenge_required"})

Я делал cli.getcookie(), но ничего не получилось.

Comment: А куки ваши где лежат?

Answer (score 0):

```
from instapy_cli import client

username = 'USERNAME'
password = 'PASSWORD'
cookie_file = 'COOKIE_FOR_USER.json' # default: `USERNAME_ig.json`

with client(username, password, cookie_file=cookie_file, 
    write_cookie_file=True) as cli:
    # get string cookies
    cookies = cli.get_cookie()
    print(type(cookies)) # == str
    print(cookies)
    # do stuffs with cli
    ig = cli.api()
    me = ig.current_user()
    print(me)
```

в файле COOKIE_FOR_USER.json должны быть ваши куки

https://github.com/instagrambot/instapy-cli/tree/master/examples